# How to validate the dates displayed are correct?

Tags: java

I need some assistance in try to pretty much assert each date within an element against the actual dates.
Basically I have 5 date tiles in my application that are displayed like so:

```
Mon 20th May
Tue 21st May
Wed 22nd May
Thu 23rd May
Fri 24th May
```

Now the elements for these tiles are the same where the day has an element of ‘id=day’ (e.g. Mon, Tue, Wed) and the date has an element of ‘id=date’ (e.g. 20th May, 21st May, 22nd May) etc.

Below explains what I am trying to do:

- In the application it always shows 5 dates
- The 5 dates shown always starts from tomorrow’s date and shows the next 5 dates excluding Sunday.

> I want to perform an assertion to check the 5 days from the date tiles
>   (e.g. Mon, Tue, Wed) matches the above criteria.
>
> I want to also perform an assertion to check the 5 dates from the date
>   tiles (e.g. 20th May, 21st May, 22nd May) matches the above criteria.
>   How can this be achieved?

I have set a little date picker below to start off with but I am not a developer so will require somebody with a little more coding knowledge and logic to help achieve this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E-dd-MMM");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // get start date
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, +1);

    // loop adding one day in each iteration
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++){
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
```

Comment: Oh ok cool, sorry about that. This is not homework (wish I was that age again), it's for commercial work but for sake of time I thought better to ask the experts rather than wasting time figuring it out myself as like I said I'm not really a developer

Comment: `Calendar` is immutable, it returns a new instance when calling `add`. You have to reassign your variable with each iteration

Comment: Well, there are no detours in life. You can't expect to be able to do "developer work" when you aren't one. Better get used to that feeling. You can't "own" such a responsibility without (some) insight about what you are doing.

Comment: @codeflush.dev You're wrong, proven by the fact that [`add(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-) has a return type of `void`, which means that `Calendar` is not immutable.

Comment: @codeflush.dev You may be confusing the terrible legacy class `Calendar` with its modern replacements, in the *java.time* package. The *java.time* classes are indeed immutable and thread-safe. The legacy classes are neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid legacy classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## `DayOfWeek`

If you need to track the day-of-week (not clear in your Question), use the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

## `Tile`

Your `Tile` class should hold a member variable of type `LocalDate`. Use smart objects rather than dumb strings. Generate localized text for display to your users, but your internal business logic should be using objects of types specific to the task.

Your class should implement the overridden `toString` method to generate text helpful when debugging or logging. Define a separate method named something like `getDisplayName` to generate text appropriate for display to the user.

```
public class Tile {
    LocalDate localDate ;
    static private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE dd MMM" , Locale.US ) ;

    public Tile( LocalDate localDateArg ) {
        this.localDate = localDateArg ;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        String output = this.localDate.format( Tile.formatter ) ;
        return output ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = Tile.class.getSimpleName() + "{ localDate:" + this.localDate.toString() + " }" ;
    }

}
```

If you really need the `th`, `st`, on your numbers, you will need to take extra steps. This feature is not built into `DateTimeFormatter`. Search on Stack Overflow for "ordinal date" as this has been covered multiple times already. I suggest adding this feature last, after you have the rest working.

## Generating tiles

> The 5 dates shown always starts from tomorrow’s date and shows the next 5 dates excluding Sunday.

So we need a list of tiles. For each new tile, discard if found to be a Sunday.

```
int limit = 5 ; 
List< Tile > tiles = new ArrayList<>( limit ) ;
```

Get today's date. Increment to each next date, omitting Sunday.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now( z ).plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Tomorrow is today plus one day.
LocalDate localDate = tomorrow ;

for ( int i = 1 ; i <= limit ; i ++ ) {
    if( localDate.getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) { // If this date is a Sunday…
        localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 ) ; // Omit Sunday, bump to the next date.
    }
    Tile tile = new Tile( localDate ) ;
    tiles.add( tile ) ;
    // Set up the next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 ) ;
}
```

> I want to perform an assertion to check the 5 days from the date tiles (e.g. Mon, Tue, Wed) matches the above criteria.

Write a little method to check our collection of tiles. I used logic similar to the method that creates the list of tiles.

```
public boolean areTilesValidByDate( final List< Tile > tiles ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull​( tiles ) ;  // Verify we were passed a list.

    int limit = 5 ;
    if( tiles.size() != limit ) {      // If unexpected size, the list cannot be valid.
        return false ;
    }

    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
    LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now( z ).plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Tomorrow is today plus one day.
    LocalDate localDate = tomorrow ;

    // Loop through the five dates we expect to find in the existing tiles.
    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= limit ; i ++ ) {
        if( localDate.getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) { // If this date is a Sunday…
            localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 ) ; // Omit Sunday, bump to the next date.
        }
        Tile tile = tiles.get( i - 1 ) ;  // Subtract one for annoying zero-based index counting rather than 1-based ordinal counting. Index-counting comes from simplistic array and byte-jumping code in old C-style languages, and is a habit the industry finds difficult to shake off.
        if( ! tile.localDate.isEqual( localDate ) {
            return false ;
        }
        // Set up the next loop.
        localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 ) ;
    }
    // If we make it to this point, the list must be valid.
    return true ;
}
```

In real work, I would not be hard-coding the time zone (the `ZoneId`).

Caveat: I never ran any of this code. You may need to fix. (⇐ The understatement is a developer joke.)

P.S. If you are making software in use by people, then you *are* a developer. Welcome to the club.

Tip: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. I helped you out this time, but perhaps should not have as we generally discourage simple duplicates on this site. All this material has been covered many many times on Stack Overflow. Struggling a bit to pull together various found nuggets will help you learn more.

Comment: Thank you very much, now that I can see the logic I will know what I need to do to find elements from an application and compare the dates to the actual dates created. :)